# in rails when I use jquery .load() for a link_to ... it opens the link in whole new tab?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I am  trying to make a chat app based on https://medium.com/@adnama.lin/live-messaging-with-rails-5-action-cable-7f009e0c1d8b 
so when user clicks the link of a user, instead of opening new page to taking him to the chat view I am trying to load the view inside a div so hope you help and feel free to ask ...

UPDATE : `$(".chat").load($(this).attr("href"));` won't work as I want to load the whole link with it's `data-method = post` and such ...

```
  <% @users.each do |other_user| %>
    <div> <%= link_to(user_chats_path(current_user, :other_user => other_user.id), method: :post, :class => "link") do %>
     <%= other_user.username %>
    <% end %>
    <% end  %>
```

Here is the jquery script :

```
  <script> 

        $(".link").on("click",function {
        $(".chat").load($(this));
return false;
        });
        </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

`load()` expects a url string but you are passing a jQuery object to it. Get the href from the link and use that.

You also need to prevent browser following that link using [`event.preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/)

Try changing to

```
$(".link").on("click",function(event) {
  event.preventDefault()
  $(".chat").load(this.href);
});
```

Comment: $(".chat").load($(this).attr("href")); won't work as I want to load the whole link with it's data-method = post and such ...

Comment: Show the rendered html for the link. Am not a rails dev but back end isn't relevant on how front end gets developed for something like this

Comment: the thing is that the link gets processed by rails then presented again as a page so I want this page to be rendered this is why I asked to load the whole link ...